# Is 'Darwin' a safe name to rely on when using platform.platform to identify the OS?

Tags: python, macos, platform, darwin

I'm looking for a consistent way to reference the generic operating system being used from within Python. I can safely assume in my case that the only OSes possible are Windows, Linux, or Mac.

For Windows and Linux, it's straightforward to map from `platform.platform` to the OS name (e.g. 'windows' or 'linux').

But for Mac, the platform name I see (on a modern macbook with OS X 10.10.1) is Darwin:

```
In [15]: platform.platform()
Out[15]: 'Darwin-14.0.0-x86_64-i386-64bit'
```

I don't know much about the Mac OS ecosystem. Is this a safe OS name to rely on? If I made a simple `dict` that mapped `'Darwin'` to `'mac'` (the shorthand name used by the system I am interfacing with), is that going to be reliable across the broad user base of Macs out there? Or will the platform name be different (such as 'macosx' or something) for older / different OS versions?

I tried googling this, but could not find consistent standards, and even found a [lengthy thread](http://bugs.python.org/issue7850) about possibly changing or extending this behavior in Python.

Comment: Yes, `Darwin` is the correct name for the OS X platform.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. I already understood *why* this happens. I am asking if it is safe. Even if the core OS is Darwin, it doesn't mean that `platform.platform` recognizes all Mac devices the same way. If it *does* recognize them the same way, that would answer my question, but would be quite distinct from the question that this is supposedly duplicating.

Comment: I'm not sure what else we can say though. The answer explains that the system is called Darwin. You should never say never, but all releases of OS X are called Darwin, so relying on Darwin is the correct way to detect Mac OS X *for the forseeable future*.

Comment: Moreover, the answer links to the Wikipedia article on Darwin, which shows what releases of Darwin have been used in what releases of OS X. Note that all 10.x releases are listed.

Comment: Well, at any rate, thank you for the clarification.